# Can the null space for a matrix with more rows than columns be restricted to 0 dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand that with a square matrix, if the rows are linearly independent, the null space will only be a point (the zero vector). But what if we have, say, a 3x2 matrix A in REF and the first two rows are linearly independent *of each other* (the bottom row being zeros), wouldn't the only solution to Ax=0 be a 2x1 zero matrix, and so the null space will again be only a point? I guess another way to word it is this- a linearly independent matrix must have a 0-dimensional null space, but not every matrix with a 0-dimensional null space is linearly independent- is this true or false?

Comment: All of what you say is true except for the parts about the notion of "linearly independent matrix" which is unclear. Does that mean (to you) a matrix with linearly independent columns? Or rows?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the rows are linearly independent (although if it's square, that implies linearly independent columns, correct?)

Comment: If it's a square matrix, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix has a $0$-dimensional null-space if and only if its *columns* are linearly independent. This follows immediately from the definitions of null-space and linear independence.

If the matrix is square, then this is equivalent to its columns being linearly independent (and to the matrix having maximal rank, and a non-zero determinant, etc.)

If the matrix has more rows than columns, then its rows cannot possibly be linearly independent, and so linear independence of the rows tells you nothing about anything.

If the matrix has more columns than rows, then its rows may or may not be linearly independent, but the matrix cannot possibly have a non-zero null-space.